# Por que não é possível definir uma interface com métodos estáticos?

Tags: java, orientação-a-objetos, interface

Gostaria de forçar algumas de minhas classes a ser implementada em Singleton, mas me deparei com a seguinte situação.

```
interface ICharacterSingleton{
    static Characters getInstancia();
}

public static class Zero extends Characters implements ICharacterSingleton {        
    private static Characters Instancia = null;
    private Zero(){     
        Layout.add("   111  ");
        Layout.add("  1   1 ");
        Layout.add("  1   1 ");
        Layout.add("  1   1 ");
        Layout.add("  1   1 ");
        Layout.add("  1   1 ");
        Layout.add("  1   1 ");
        Layout.add("   111  ");                         
    }

    public static Characters getInstancia() {
        if(Instancia == null)
            Instancia = new Zero();         
        return Instancia;
    }               
}
```

Não posso definir um método estático para uma interface? existe uma outra saída para essa situação?

Comment: É bom observar que - em Java 8 pelo menos - você [**pode sim** ter métodos estáticos nas interfaces](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html). Entretanto, você não pode usá-los para implementar um singleton, como bem explicado nas respostas. Outras linguagens (como Python) diferenciam entre *static methods* e *class methods* - esses últimos considerando herança - mas mesmo assim não dá pra exigir que uma classe derivada dê sua própria implementação de um método de classe. Como disse Math: "não é possível obrigar por meio de contrato que uma classe seja Singleton".

Comment: P.S. Se não fosse o problema de herança múltipla, você poderia criar uma classe base que mantém um registro das instâncias criadas - através de um `Map` com `this.getClass()` como chave - e lança uma exceção se mais de uma instância da mesma classe for criada. Toda classe que herdar dela seria então *de facto* um singleton. Essa classe base poderia até ter um método utilitário para se recuperar a instância - servindo de fábrica para esses objetos, e centralizando sua criação e acesso de modo padronizado. Posso postar isso como resposta se quiser, mas ainda não se aplica ao uso de interfaces.

Comment: @utluiz eu gostei da ideia do SingletonFactory Porem eu terei varias classe herdando de "Characters" e todas elas seguindo o mesmo conceito gerando um mapa de carácter formando o numero em ascii, no exemplo acima eu tenho a classe Zero, terei a Um, Dois e assim vai todas herdando Characteres no caso do SingletonFactory Eu teria que ter uma fabrica de objeto para cada classe como eu administraria todas essas instancias singleton?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Transformei meu comentário em resposta devido ao tamanho.*

O problema parece ser perfeitamente solucionado unindo o conceito do padrão de projeto *Factory Method* com o *Singleton*, isto é, um método que fabrica uma instância única de uma classe.

Abaixo colocarei duas implementações possíveis...

## Abordagem #1: um método e um atributo para cada classe

```java
public abstract SingletonFactory {

    private static Zero zero = new Zero(); 
    public static Zero getInstanciaZero() {
        return zero;
    }

    private static Um um = new Um(); 
    public static Um getInstanciaUm() {
        return  um;
    }

    //...

}
```

## Abordagem #2: um método genérico que recebe o número como parâmetro

```java
public abstract SingletonFactory {

    private static Map<Byte, ICharacterSingleton> numberMap = new HashMap<>(); 

    static {
        numberMap.put(0, new Zero());
        numberMap.put(1, new Um());
        //...
    }

    public static ICharacterSingleton getInstancia(Byte numero) {
        return numberMap.get(numero);
    }

}
```

Comment: utluiz A segunda abordagem parece ser ótima para mim, qual a melhor forma para encapsular o objeto ICharacterSingleton para que apenas o SingletonFactory instancie ele? pois caso o contrario o objeto poderia ser instanciado sem a fabrica certo? e então eu quebraria seu singleton.

Comment: @TuyoshiVinicius A interface pode ser pública, afinal é só uma interface. Quanto às classes `Zero`, `Um` e as outras, uma forma é deixá-las no mesmo pacote da `SingletonFactory` e deixar o construtor delas sem o `public`, de forma que sejam visíveis apenas para classes do mesmo pacote. Outra forma é declarar essas classes **dentro** da classe `SingletonFactory` (*inner classes*) com o construtor *private*, de forma que apenas de dentro da classe `SingletonFactory` seja possível instanciá-las.

Comment: valew cara, sua abordagem e a ótima explicação do @Math foram as combinações perfeitas, pena que não é possível marcar duas resposta como certas.

Answer (score 12):

Métodos em interfaces são implicitamente `public` e `abstract`.

Ou seja, por mais que você declare um método assim em sua interface:

```
public interface MinhaInterface {
    void teste();
}
```

Implicitamente o que você está fazendo é:

```
public interface MinhaInterface {
    public abstract void teste();
}
```

Portanto, o problema não é a interface, o problema é o modificador `abstract` que conflita com o modificador `static`. Exemplificando, você também não pode fazer tal coisa para uma classe:

```
public abstract class MinhaClasse {
    public abstract static void teste();
}
```

O erro é o mesmo que tentar criar um método estático em uma interface. O motivo desses dois modificadores serem conflitantes é simples: se o método é estático significa que ele pertence a classe, entretanto se ele é abstrato significa que ele não possui implementação, oras, para quê você vai acessar um método de uma classe que não possui implementação?

Basicamente:

- `static` impede que você sobrescreva o método, se uma subclasse usar a mesma assinatura de um método estático, então essa subclasse estará redefinindo o método e não sobrescrevendo; enquanto que
- `abstract` obriga que a primeira subclasse concreta implemente tal método, por meio da sobrescrita.

Por isso são conflitantes.

A solução para seu caso, vou pensar mais um pouco, mas a princípio diria que não é possível obrigar por meio de contrato que uma classe seja Singleton.

Comment: Ótima explicação muito obrigado.

Answer (score 4):

O interessante da `interface` é poder separar a implementação da classe do "contrato" que diz o que ela tem. Dessa forma, posso receber um objeto que sei que implementa a interface e trabalhar com ele sem saber qual é a sua classe:

```
IEnumeravel obj = ...;
obj.BuscaEnumerador();
```

No pequeno exemplo acima eu não sei a classe de obj, pode ser cada hora uma, pode ser recebida como parâmetro. O contrato é feito de forma que sei que o objeto que chegar vai ter o método para eu chamar.

Métodos estáticos são chamados pela classe, eu preciso saber que estou trabalhando com a classe `Zero` para chamar o método:

```
Zero.getInstancia();
```

Answer (score 2):

Porque seria uma contradicao de como o Java faz para invocar um metodo estatico.

Um metodo estastico e independente de instancias, correto? Logo, ele pode ser executado direto do ".class".

Agora, se voce pudesse ter um metodo estatico numa interface, o Java teria que procurar uma implementacao em particular da interface para poder executar o metodo.

Contudo, ele poderia deixar voce fazer algo como:

```
public interface Coisa {
  public static int f() {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Mas voce nao pode :P

Answer (score 1):

Existem, basicamente, dois tipos de métodos: métodos de instâncias e métodos estáticos (de classes).

Esse conceito pertence ao paradigma orientado a objetos, não é particular de nenhum linguagem.

Como os métodos estáticos pertencem a classe, quando criamos um método estático em uma classe, ao iniciar o programa, no classe loader, são verificadas quais classes têm métodos estáticos. Quando identificada uma classe com um método estático, a implementação desse método é colocada em um escopo global, que pode ser acessado através do tipo que mantém a classe estática.

### Por que não é possível implementar métodos estáticos em interfaces.

Pelo fato do classe loader procurar *uma implementação* para colocá-la em um escopo global, não é permitido colocar método estáticos em interfaces, *porque interfaces não implementam os métodos, elas mantém apenas suas assinaturas.*

Logo, não é possível implementar métodos estáticos em interfaces.

Answer (score -2):

Não é possível pois uma interface não pode ser instanciada como uma classe concreta ou seja ela não possui método construtor, quando tenta acessar um método estático internamente a classe e instanciada e fica pronta para ter o acesso direto aquele método construtor.

[]'s

Comment: **Errado:** "Não é possível pois uma interface não pode ser instanciada como uma classe concreta ou seja ela não possui método construtor" - uma coisa não tem nada a ver com a outra; **Errado também:** "quando tenta acessar um método estático internamente a classe é instanciada e fica pronta para ter o acesso direto aquele método construtor" - a classe não precisa ser instanciada para ter um método estático acessado. Ela só é instanciada quando se usa o operador new. PS: interfaces podem ter atributos estáticos sem o menor problema (implicitamente na interface todos são estáticos).

Comment: Obrigado pela correção.